# Set tab size ('\t') for unlimited amount of tabs in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, special-characters, jtextpane

JTextArea traditionally has a setTabSize method. JTextPane, however, does not. I've tried finding a solution for this, but I always end up bumping into the TabStop/TabSet method, like so:

```
    TabStop[] tabs = new TabStop[5];
    tabs[0] = new TabStop(30, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
    tabs[1] = ..........................
    tabs[2] = ......................... 

    TabSet tabSet = new TabSet(tabs);

    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet as = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, 
            StyleConstants.TabSet, tabSet);

    setParagraphAttributes(as, false);
```

The problem with this method is that it implies a limited amount of tabs. Whenever I use the tab button beyond 5 times, it just prints a space. Is there a way to have an unending amount of same-sized tabs whenever the tab button is pressed, or do I just need to create a big array of TabStop?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://java-sl.com/tip_default_tabstop_size.html)?

Comment: Yes, it "prints" 5 tabs in the JTextPane and after that, whenever I press tab, it just prints a space.